# ColdFusion: XmlParse does not preserve Carriage Return

Tags: coldfusion, newline, tostring, carriage-return

Test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node>line1
line2
line3</node>
```

CF code:

```
<cfset xmlfile = ExpandPath("test.xml")>
<cffile action="read" file="#xmlfile#" variable="xmlstring">
<cffile action="write" file="test1.xml" output="#xmlstring#">

<cfset xmldoc = XmlParse(xmlstring)> 
<cfset xmltext = ToString(xmldoc)>
<cffile action="write" file="test2.xml" output="#xmltext#">
```

The input file test.xml file is in CRLF format, UTF-8 encoded, 77 bytes.
The first output file (test1.xml) is in CRLF format, ANSI encoded, 76 bytes.
The second output file (test2.xml) is in UNIX format, ANSI encoded, 71 bytes.

The contents of the XML node in the input file is `line1 Chr(13)Chr(10) line2 Chr(13)Chr(10) line3` (whitespaces for readability).
The contents of the XML node in the first output file is the same as above.
The contents of the XML node in the second output file is `line1 Chr(10) line2 Chr(10) line3`.

Any ideas why the carriage return character `Chr(13)` was not preserved after the `XmlParse/ToString` sequence?

**UPDATE:**
The problem lies only with XmlParse. It's not about ToString or cffile.
Here is a more relevant example - you can test for yourselves:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="xmlvar">
<nodes>
    <node>
line1
line2
line3
    </node>
</nodes>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfset vtext = "#xmlvar#">
<cfset vtext = Replace(vtext,Chr(10),'LF','All')>
<cfset vtext = Replace(vtext,Chr(13),'CR','All')>
<cfdump var = "#vtext#">
<!--- outputs CRLF<nodes>CRLF <node>CRLFline1CRLFline2CRLFline3CRLF </node>CRLF</nodes>CRLF --->
<cfset xmldoc = XmlParse(xmlvar)>
<cfset vtext = "#xmldoc.nodes.node.XmlText#">
<cfset vtext = Replace(vtext,Chr(10),'LF','All')>
<cfset vtext = Replace(vtext,Chr(13),'CR','All')>
<cfdump var = "#vtext#">
<!--- outputs LFline1LFline2LFline3LF --->
```

Comment: CF 8, Windows XP Professional SP3
Also reproduced on CF 9.

Comment: It looks to me, based on a bit of searching, that by default XML Parsers are nto expected to preserve whitespace, since most of the time whitespace is meaningless in data and where it is important (in layout) is rare. But it looks like there is an attribute that you can set to tell the parser to preserve the whitespace.  I have no idea if it works in this case because I did not have any of the problems you are describing on my system. ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-white-space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML Parsers normalize the CR/LF to LF per the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends). To keep the CR/LF EOL use entity references. See below:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="xmlvar">
<nodes>
    <node>
      line1&#x000D;&#x000A;
      line2&#x000D;&#x000A;
      line3&#x000D;&#x000A;
    </node>
</nodes>
</cfsavecontent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the parameter charset='utf-8' in the cffile tag ?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce anything that you are talking about with ColdFusion 9.0.1 on Mac OSX. White space is being preserved just as it goes in.  I tried both of your examples above and they worked (mostly) as expected.  I actually did not see any CRs in the replace()s, I only saw LFs. But it maintained them all.

Comment: OSX doesn't use CR/LF as it's EOL marker. Wikipedia has a list of EOL chars and the systems that use them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations